# Условие проверки дополнительного поля MOX revo

Tags: modx, условия

```
[[+tv.advPhone:!empty=`<h4>Контакты</h4>`]]
                                [[+tv.advPhone:!empty=`[[+tv.advPhone]]`]]
                                [[+tv.advEmail:!empty=`[[+tv.advEmail]]`]]
```

В такой конструкции проверяются условия
1. Если дополнительное поле advPhone не пустое, то выводить заголовок Контакты+номер телефона
2. Если дополнительное поле advEmail не пустое, то выводить email адрес

Как правильно составить условие проверки двух полей advPhone и advEmail на пустоту, если одно из них заполнено, то вывести заголовок контакты+информацию доп. полей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение, которое у меня заработало в соответствии с поставленными задачами.

Если поле advPhone не пустое, или поле advEmail не пустое, то вывести заголовок Контакты + содержимое поля

```
 [[+tv.advPhone:isnot=``:or:if=`[[+tv.advEmail]]`:isnot=``:then=`<h4>Контакты</h4>`]]
                            [[+tv.advPhone:!empty=`[[+tv.advPhone]]`]]
                            [[+tv.advEmail:!empty=`[[+tv.advEmail]]`]]
```

Answer (score 0):

С помощью простого условия так не получится, нельзя проверить несколько полей. Можно сделать с помощью небольшого сниппета:

Создаете новый сниппет с названием к примеру `advContact`:

```
<?php
if (empty($advPhone) and empty($advEmail)) return '';
return '<h4>Контакты</h4>'.$advPhone.$advEmail;
```

Вызываете на своей странице так:

```
[[advContact?&advPhone=`[[+tv.advPhone]]`&advEmail=`[[+tv.advEmail]]`]]
```